# cypher how get relation between every two node and the distance from start node?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cypher-3.1

I have some nodes and relation like `A -> B ->C -> D`; and`B->D`So the B C D is a loop, now I want get all relations and each relation distance from node A;
I expect result like:

```
{startNode: A, endNode: B, rel:FRIEND, distanceFromAtoEndnode: 1},
{startNode: B, endNode: C, rel:FRIEND, distanceFromAtoEndnode: 2},
{startNode: C, endNode: D, rel:FRIEND, distanceFromAtoEndnode: 3},
{startNode: B, endNode: D, rel:FRIEND, distanceFromAtoEndnode: 2}
```

and my cypher:

```
match p=(n:Person {name:"A"})-[r*1..9]-(m:Person) return last(r) as rel,length(p) as distanceFromAtoEndnode
```

but this always get one more item I donot need:

```
{startNode: D, endNode: C, rel:FRIEND, distanceFromAtoEndnode: 3},
```

and  if there are double loop like "8" then the result is worse

how can I write the cypher?

Comment: the relation direction is uncertain so I can not add -> on my cypher sql also the > is not solution fro double loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's easy enough to get distance to end nodes, your requirement to get the last relationship, with the results you want, will be tough (maybe impossible?) to get with just Cypher, since since relationships may be traversed multiple times depending on the connectedness of the graph, and since the same relationships will occur as the last relationship of paths of differing lengths.

If you absolutely need this, then you can use [APOC path expander procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_path_expander) to ensure that each relationship is only ever traversed once, so you won't get the same relationship as a result but for a different path.

An example of usage that should give you the results you want:

```
MATCH (n:Person {name:"A"})
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(n, {uniqueness:'RELATIONSHIP_GLOBAL', minLevel:1, maxLevel:9, labelFilter:'>Person'}) YIELD path
WITH last(relationships(path)) as rel, length(path) as distanceFromAtoEndnode
RETURN rel {startNode:startNode(rel).name, endNode:endNode(rel).name, rel:type(rel)} as rel, distanceFromAtoEndnode
```

As for pure Cypher solutions, you may get hangs on highly connected graphs, since Cypher's expansion tries to find all possible paths. But here you go.

To find shortest distance for all connected nodes:

```
MATCH path=(:Person {name:"A"})-[*1..9]-(other:Person)
RETURN other, min(length(path)) as shortestDistance
```

And to find all relationships connecting all connected nodes:

```
MATCH path=(:Person {name:"A"})-[*1..9]-(:Person)
WITH distinct last(relationships(path)) as rel
RETURN rel {startNode:startNode(rel).name, endNode:endNode(rel).name, rel:type(rel)} as rel
```

Comment: thanks a lot, would you help me ,what if I query two times, one for unique two-node relations collection and one for every node the distance from A, what is the best cypher sql

Comment: With or without APOC? You should already have both results from the above query.

Comment: i mean without APOC

Comment: Updated with pure cypher queries